# Qual a indicação de se usar Redis com IoTs?

Tags: redis

Eu tenho em minha mãos um projeto de integração de dispositivos de uma empresa para uma plataforma web. Esse [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXQV1EvmG0Q) mostra uma idéia geral do projeto.

Trata-se de várias máquinas, que enviam informações (status, temperatura, velocidade, ..., etc) à um servidor central, (um banco de dados MySQL).
E de uma outra direção, essa máquinas recebem instruções de vários usuários para: parar um processo em andamento, diminuir ou aumentar a velocidade, diminuir temperatura, ... etc.

O meu trabalho é integrar essa arquitetura na web, em tempo real, como no vídeo que mostrei acima.

Receber a informação em tempo real das máquina e exibir no browser, já está feito. Utilizei basicamente MySql + SSE + PHP + Bootstrap. Tbm posso interagir tom tablets e smart phones. Isso já está feito.

A minha dúvida reside na direção Browser ==> Dispositivos.

Na arquitetura atual este processo passa por REDIS. Como eu nunca trabalhei com essa tecnologia fui fazer uma pesquisa e achei esse [site](http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/7/6/11-common-web-use-cases-solved-in-redis.html) que mostra algumas aplicações. Estou querendo deixar todo o processo usando Mysql e abandonar o Redis. Para isso preciso entender qual a importância dessa tecnologia nos projetos IoT, para saber se o Mysql vai responder às necessidades.

Até onde entendi, trata-se de um um banco de dados NoSql muito suado para cache.

Mas não consigo ver onde o Redis é importante no desenvolvimento com IoT.

Alguém que já tenha trabalhado com essas duas tecnologias IoT e Redis, poderia me explicar?

Answer (score 0):

Redis tem I/O mais rápido porque fica tudo na memória, mas por conta disso não é adequado se você precisar persistir esses dados (mas existem maneiras de gravar no disco). Geralmente não é necessário gravar o histórico de dados em projetos IoT, apenas transferir mensagens o mais rápido possível.

Por exemplo se você for usar um raspberry pi e ficar escrevendo no SD dele, vai desgastá-lo rápido. Um HDD requer bem mais energia, poucos equipamentos embarcados usam HDD e mesmo assim HDDs eventualmente falham e precisam ser substituídos. É incomum ficar substituindo peças de dispositivos embarcados.

No entanto você pode usar MySQL também, com um tabela usando engine MyISAM, que deixa tudo na memória. Mas você falou que já tem um servidor, não sei se isso se enquadra em IoT. Você incluiu um vídeo com um trem de brinquedo, nem imagino em como isso se relaciona com o seu projeto.

Mas é isso: redis é rápido e não persistente. IoT usa muito redis porque ele consome poucos recursos, mas obviamente tem menos funcionalidades que um RDBMS. Se você tem um servidor grande, possui recursos para deixar uma estrutura de dados persistente e usar ferramentas menos econômicas.